# Is there a way to let NetBeans work with Amazon-ec2 disk space?

Tags: netbeans, macos, amazon-ec2, mount

I'm sick of using vim to develop on some far Amazon-ec2 machine.

I'm wondering if there is any way to Use NetBeans on my laptop to develop on and run the code on that machine. Basically I want a way to let NetBeans operate on an external disk space that I connect to using SSH, In my case I'm using Mac OS X 10.6.3 locally and the external disk space is located on some Amazon-ec2 machine.

Any ideas? Or solution for such cases when a developer needs to code on some external machine and use a good IDE?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it supports SFTP, you're all set: http://blogs.oracle.com/netbeansphp/entry/sftp_support_added.

Another way of doing that is connecting with winscp and editing the files locally (with your preferred editor) - winscp will sync the files as needed.

A commercial alternative is [expandrive](http://www.expandrive.com/mac).